# Fonts have blue shadows in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, fonts, appearance, gpu-driver

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 (Linux kernel 5.4.0.26-generic), in my desktop from a USB disk. After installing nvidia driver version 450, all fonts in the system have blue shadows. See the following screenshots for understanding:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

I tried to downgrade to version 440.100 of nvidia-driver, but the problem is still there.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't see any blue shadows on those screenshots.

Comment: Disable font smoothing (font antialiasing): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts